# Unable to resolve dependency for generic repository using autofac

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, autofac, asp.net-core-webapi

I am working with .net core API and resolving my dependency using autofac. However somehow I am not able to resolve dependency for my Generic Repository.

Can someone guide what I have done wrong.

**startup.cs**

```
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

builder.RegisterType<UnitOfWork>().As<IUnitOfWork>()
    .InstancePerLifetimeScope();

builder.RegisterType<DatabaseFactory>().As<IDatabaseFactory>()
.InstancePerLifetimeScope();

//This is the place which is not working for me
builder.RegisterGeneric(typeof(Repository<>)).As(typeof(IRepository<>)).InstancePerLifetimeScope();

builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(typeof(SizeRepository).Assembly)
    .Where(t => t.Name.EndsWith("Repository"))
    .AsImplementedInterfaces()
    .InstancePerLifetimeScope();

builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(typeof(UserService).Assembly)
    .Where(t => t.Name.EndsWith("Service"))
    .AsImplementedInterfaces()
    .InstancePerLifetimeScope();

builder.Populate(services);
var container = builder.Build();
//Create the IServiceProvider based on the container.
return new AutofacServiceProvider(container);
```

**UnitOfWork.cs**

```
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace MakeTalk.Data.Infrastructure
{
public class UnitOfWork : IUnitOfWork
{
    #region Local variable

    private readonly IDatabaseFactory databaseFactory;
    private MakeTalkEntities dataContext;

    #endregion

    #region Constructor
    public UnitOfWork(IDatabaseFactory databaseFactory)
    {
        this.databaseFactory = databaseFactory;
    }
    #endregion

    #region Property
    protected MakeTalkEntities DataContext => dataContext ?? (dataContext = databaseFactory.Get());
    #endregion

    #region Methods
    /// <summary>
    /// Commit changes 
    /// </summary>
    /// <history>Created : 01-04-2018</history>
    public void Commit()
    {
        DataContext.SaveChanges();
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Commit Async changes
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    /// <history>Created : 01-04-2018</history>
    public async Task<int> CommitAsync()
    {
        return await DataContext.SaveChangesAsync();
    }

    #endregion

}
}
```

**Repository.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Linq.Expressions;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;


namespace MakeTalk.Data.Infrastructure
{
    public class Repository<T> : IRepository<T> where T : class
    {
        #region Variable / Properties  
        private MakeTalkEntities dataContext;
        private readonly DbSet<T> dbSet;
        protected MakeTalkEntities DataContext => dataContext ?? (dataContext = DatabaseFactory.Get());
    protected IDatabaseFactory DatabaseFactory
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }
    #endregion

    #region Constructor
    protected Repository(IDatabaseFactory databaseFactory)
    {
        DatabaseFactory = databaseFactory;
        dbSet = DataContext.Set<T>();
    }
    #endregion

    #region Sync Methods

    // all methods ...
    #endregion
}
}
```

**DatabaseFactory.cs**

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace MakeTalk.Data.Infrastructure
{
    public class DatabaseFactory : Disposable, IDatabaseFactory
    {
        private MakeTalkEntities dataContext;

        public MakeTalkEntities Get()
        {
            return dataContext ?? (dataContext = new MakeTalkEntities(new DbContextOptions<MakeTalkEntities>()));
        }
        protected override void DisposeCore()
        {
            dataContext?.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

**MakeTalkEntities.cs**

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using MakeTalk.Data.Configuration;
using MakeTalk.Model;

namespace MakeTalk.Data
{
    public class MakeTalkEntities : DbContext
    {
        #region Constructor

        public MakeTalkEntities(DbContextOptions options)
        {

        }

        #endregion

        #region DB Properties 
        // db sets 

        #endregion

        #region Methods

        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {


            // ReSharper disable once AssignNullToNotNullAttribute
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("Some-Connection");

            base.OnConfiguring(optionsBuilder);
        }
        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {

            // all configutaion 

            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        }
        #endregion

    }
}
```

Is there anything wrong with code? I am able  to resolver my other repository & services just facing issue with Generic Repository 
**builder.RegisterGeneric(typeof(Repository<>)).As(typeof(IRepository<>)).InstancePerLifetimeScope();**

At time of using this generic repository I gets following error

> Autofac.Core.DependencyResolutionException: An error occurred during the activation of a particular registration. See the inner exception for details. Registration: Activator = CommonService (ReflectionActivator), Services = [MakeTalk.Service.ICommonService], Lifetime = Autofac.Core.Lifetime.CurrentScopeLifetime, Sharing = Shared, Ownership = OwnedByLifetimeScope ---> An error occurred during the activation of a particular registration. See the inner exception for details. Registration: Activator = Repository`1 (ReflectionActivator), Services = [MakeTalk.Data.Infrastructure.IRepository`1[[MakeTalk.Model.ExhibitionRequestStatus, MakeTalk.Model, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]], Lifetime = Autofac.Core.Lifetime.CurrentScopeLifetime, Sharing = Shared, Ownership = OwnedByLifetimeScope ---> No constructors on type 'MakeTalk.Data.Infrastructure.Repository`1[MakeTalk.Model.ExhibitionRequestStatus]' can be found with the constructor finder 'Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.DefaultConstructorFinder'. (See inner exception for details.) (See inner exception for details.) ---> Autofac.Core.DependencyResolutionException: An error occurred during the activation of a particular registration. See the inner exception for details. Registration: Activator = Repository`1 (ReflectionActivator), Services = [MakeTalk.Data.Infrastructure.IRepository`1[[MakeTalk.Model.ExhibitionRequestStatus, MakeTalk.Model, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]], Lifetime = Autofac.Core.Lifetime.CurrentScopeLifetime, Sharing = Shared, Ownership = OwnedByLifetimeScope ---> No constructors on type 'MakeTalk.Data.Infrastructure.Repository`1[MakeTalk.Model.ExhibitionRequestStatus]' can be found with the constructor finder 'Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.DefaultConstructorFinder'. (See inner exception for details.) ---> Autofac.Core.DependencyResolutionException: No constructors on type 'MakeTalk.Data.Infrastructure.Repository`1[MakeTalk.Model.ExhibitionRequestStatus]' can be found with the constructor finder 'Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.DefaultConstructorFinder'.
>      at Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.ReflectionActivator.ActivateInstance(IComponentContext context, IEnumerable`1 parameters)
>      at Autofac.Core.Resolving.InstanceLookup.Activate(IEnumerable`1 parameters)
>      --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>      at Autofac.Core.Resolving.InstanceLookup.Activate(IEnumerable`1 parameters)
>      at Autofac.Core.Lifetime.LifetimeScope.GetOrCreateAndShare(Guid id, Func`1 creator)
>      at Autofac.Core.Resolving.InstanceLookup.Execute()
>      at Autofac.Core.Resolving.ResolveOperation.GetOrCreateInstance(ISharingLifetimeScope currentOperationScope, IComponentRegistration registration, IEnumerable`1 parameters)
>      at Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.ConstructorParameterBinding.Instantiate()
>      at Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.ReflectionActivator.ActivateInstance(IComponentContext context, IEnumerable`1 parameters)
>      at Autofac.Core.Resolving.InstanceLookup.Activate(IEnumerable`1 parameters)
>      --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>      at Autofac.Core.Resolving.InstanceLookup.Activate(IEnumerable`1 parameters)
>      at Autofac.Core.Lifetime.LifetimeScope.GetOrCreateAndShare(Guid id, Func`1 creator)
>      at Autofac.Core.Resolving.InstanceLookup.Execute()
>      at Autofac.Core.Resolving.ResolveOperation.GetOrCreateInstance(ISharingLifetimeScope currentOperationScope, IComponentRegistration registration, IEnumerable`1 parameters)
>      at Autofac.Core.Resolving.ResolveOperation.Execute(IComponentRegistration registration, IEnumerable`1 parameters)
>      at Autofac.ResolutionExtensions.TryResolveService(IComponentContext context, Service service, IEnumerable`1 parameters, Object& instance)
>      at Autofac.ResolutionExtensions.ResolveOptionalService(IComponentContext context, Service service, IEnumerable`1 parameters)
>      at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ActivatorUtilities.GetService(IServiceProvider sp, Type type, Type requiredBy, Boolean isDefaultParameterRequired)
>      at lambda_method(Closure , IServiceProvider , Object[] )
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Controllers.ControllerActivatorProvider.<>c__DisplayClass4_0.b__0(ControllerContext controllerContext)
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Controllers.ControllerFactoryProvider.<>c__DisplayClass5_0.g__CreateController|0(ControllerContext controllerContext)
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeInnerFilterAsync()
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeNextResourceFilter()
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContext context)
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeFilterPipelineAsync()
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeAsync()
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointRoutingMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you look at the error message you can see this

> No constructors on type `MakeTalk.Data.Infrastructure.Repository1[MakeTalk.Model.ExhibitionRequestStatus]` can be found with the constructor finder `Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.DefaultConstructorFinder`.

it means that *Autofac* can't find a constructor on type `Repository<T>`. If you look at this type the constructor is marked as `protected` which means *Autofac* doesn't have access to it.

To fix this error you have to change the constructor to `public`